# how to shift an object in array to be on top in javascript / vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
const a = [{
    "iso2": "KH",
    "countryName": "Cambodia",
    "nationality": "Cambodian"
},
{
    "iso2": "KI",
    "countryName": "Kiribati",
    "nationality": "I-Kiribati"
},
{
    "iso2": "KM",
    "countryName": "Comoros",
    "nationality": "Comoran, Comorian"
},
{
    "iso2": "KN",
    "countryName": "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
    "nationality": "Kittitian or Nevisian"
}];
```

i have an array from Get Api list and i intended to move isow = KN to be on top of the list to be sync with select list option.
i know about push and unshift method. but is there is another easiest way to move an object in Array to be on top of the list?

Comment: There's also `splice()`, which lets you insert and remove anywhere in the list. But if it's always first and last, use `push`, `pop`, `shift`, and `unshift`.

Comment: do you want the other items to retain their order?

Comment: if the object is in the mid i could use splice? and if i want it to be on top i need to shift or push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to sort the complete array if you just want to move the element to the start and do not care about the order of other elements.

You can simply find the index of the element and swap it with the first one.

```js
const a = [{
 "iso2": "KH",
 "countryName": "Cambodia",
 "nationality": "Cambodian"
},
{
 "iso2": "KI",
 "countryName": "Kiribati",
 "nationality": "I-Kiribati"
},
{
 "iso2": "KM",
 "countryName": "Comoros",
 "nationality": "Comoran, Comorian"
},
{
 "iso2": "KN",
 "countryName": "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
 "nationality": "Kittitian or Nevisian"
}];

let index = a.findIndex(e => e.iso2 === 'KN');

a[0] = (_=a[index], a[index] = a[0],_);
console.log(a)
```

Or can remove the element using `Array.splice` and then unshift.

```js
const a = [{
 "iso2": "KH",
 "countryName": "Cambodia",
 "nationality": "Cambodian"
},
{
 "iso2": "KI",
 "countryName": "Kiribati",
 "nationality": "I-Kiribati"
},
{
 "iso2": "KN",
 "countryName": "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
 "nationality": "Kittitian or Nevisian"
},
{
 "iso2": "KM",
 "countryName": "Comoros",
 "nationality": "Comoran, Comorian"
}];

let index = a.findIndex(e => e.iso2 === 'KN');
e = a.splice(index,1);
a.unshift(...e)
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.sort` to re-order the array as you wish.

```js
const a = [{
    "iso2": "KH",
    "countryName": "Cambodia",
    "nationality": "Cambodian"
  },
  {
    "iso2": "KI",
    "countryName": "Kiribati",
    "nationality": "I-Kiribati"
  },
  {
    "iso2": "KM",
    "countryName": "Comoros",
    "nationality": "Comoran, Comorian"
  },
  {
    "iso2": "KN",
    "countryName": "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
    "nationality": "Kittitian or Nevisian"
  }
];

a.sort((item1) => item1.iso2 === 'KN' ? -1 : 1);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: sorry, but actually the are more than just this data. and the kn is actually in the mid of data.

Comment: all country name and iso in world

Comment: And you want to move only 'KN' to the start?

Comment: I've changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 let data = [
      {
        iso2: "KH",
        countryName: "Cambodia",
        nationality: "Cambodian"
      },
      {
        iso2: "KI",
        countryName: "Kiribati",
        nationality: "I-Kiribati"
      },
      {
        iso2: "KM",
        countryName: "Comoros",
        nationality: "Comoran, Comorian"
      },
      {
        iso2: "KN",
        countryName: "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
        nationality: "Kittitian or Nevisian"
      }
    ];

    let one = "KN";
    data.sort((x, y) => (x.iso2 == one ? -1 : y.iso2 == one ? 1 : 0));
    console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reverse your array if you want to last object on top.
a.reverse();